# continuous function bound problem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, show that there exist points $x_1, x_2\in[a,b]$, such that the range of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is equal to $[f(x_1),f(x_2)]$.

I know it is true intuitively, but don't know how to prove it formally. I know that f is continuous on $[a,b]$ and therefore f is uniformly continuous, then I tried to prove the function values are also bounded. But I don't know how to proceed from there. Or should i use intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ achieves a maximum and a minimum,
i.e., there exist $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$, such that
$$
f(x_1)=\max_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad
f(x_2)=\min_{x\in [a,b]}f(x).
$$
Hence $f\big([a,b]\big)\subset [\,f(x_1),f(x_2)]$.

Equality above follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: The reason we know that it achieves a max and min is that (1)if it's not bounded there exist $x_n$ with $|f(x_n)|>n$ and there is a subsequence of $x_n$ converging to some $x$ where $f$ would be discontinuous.(2) If $f(a_n)$ converges to $\sup f$ there exists a subsequence of $a_n$ converging to some $a$ and continuity implies $f(a)=\sup f$. And similarly for $\inf f$.